# Windows UnRar Batch script need to ignore .part02.rar through part99.rar extensions

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, rar, winrar

I have two windows batch scripts that both work to recurse the folder they are placed in, and extract every .rar file into the folder of the rar files.

however when a folder uses the structure:

```
file.part01.rar
file.part02.rar
file.part03.rar  ect..
```

the script chokes as it tries to extrtact each of these files (since they match .rar extension) and presents the user with FileExtract.bla already exists: Overwrite? (Y)es / (N)o ?  X times the number of rar archive parts (often 20 or 30 times).

Ive been trying to figure out how in my batch script to first filter out any files with extensions part02.rar to part99.rar (but *not* part01.rar as this is the file i DO want to extract) before it is passed to the "DO" / unrar command.

here are two different batch files that both work in the same way (and fail in the same way on part02.rar files):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "sourcefolder=."
FOR /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a IN (*.r*) DO (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('echo %%~xa^|findstr /r "\.r.*"') DO
("C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~a")
)
```

and #2:

```
@echo on
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%  
    cd %%F
       FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
    )
popd
)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the script chokes as it tries to extrtact each of these files (since
>   they match .rar extension) and presents the user with FileExtract.bla
>   already exists: Overwrite? (Y)es / (N)o ? X times the number of rar
>   archive parts (often 20 or 30 times).

Why not just simply pipe **"N"** to the `7z` commands to tell them pick the **"N"** option for **"NO"** if presented with it?

I'm not sure if it these commands always start with the applicable `file.part01.rar` first, and then moves onto `file.part02.rar`, `file.part03.rar`, and so on in sequential order, or if that is really even important for the duplicate files extracted content wise.

If the automation is being held up only this option to be selected when the issue exists, then selecting that **"N"** option automatically should allow the other files to also be extracted and for the automation to finish.

So the issue is these RAR files with the **part[02-99].rar** file names extract files that already exist where those are being extracted so it asks it you want to overwrite the existing file or not.

If it extracts the **01** named files first and then tries all subsequent matching file names where it has an extract file overwrite conflict then this should work.

If this works as expected, then that'd make it very minimal change to what's needed in your batch script logic (see examples below).

### #1

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL disableDelayedExpansion
SET "sourcefolder=."
FOR /R "%sourcefolder%" %%a IN (*.r*) DO (
    FOR /f "delims=" %%b IN ('echo %%~xa^|findstr /r "\.r.*"') DO
(ECHO N | "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%~a")
)
```

### #2

```
@echo on
FOR /D /r %%F in ("*") DO (
    pushd %CD%  
    cd %%F
       FOR %%X in (*.rar *.zip) DO (
        ECHO N | "C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x "%%X"
    )
popd
)
```

Comment: Its really embarrassing the amount of time i have spent trying to troubleshoot this problem,  there are many times i had even thought about scripting something like auto-hotkey to continually send a "N" keystroke as a rough fix.... I just cant believe i didnt think about your solution.  It works perfectly!  and was right there in-front of my face.. i come from the linux world where i would have solved this much faster            , i just didnt think about using batch like that.  Thanks alot!

Comment: StackExchange is a beautiful community. I encourage you to use it more for both questions and answers as you have time do so. I'm glad you fixed your issue and I'm happy to help!